# How to submit Multiple Struts 2 forms on same page with one submit button?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I tried with Struts2-jquery submit tags and included all the forms to formIds but it doesn't work.

It works individually when I mention each formid in separate submit tags.

```
<sj:submit value="Submit GeneralInfo"  formIds="GeneralInfo"  /> 
<sj:submit value="Submit Corrugated1"  formIds="Corrugated1" />
<sj:submit value="Submit Corrugated2"  formIds="Corrugated2"  />
<sj:submit value="Submit CustomerVendor"  formIds="CustomerVendor"  />
<sj:submit value="Submit Stock"  formIds="Stock" />
<s:submit value="Print" id="print" theme="simple"/> 
<s:submit value="Cancel" id="cancel" theme="simple"/>
```

Each form has different action and action class. Also, each action class associated with xml validation.

Comment: Is this a DDOS attack generator ? :D

Answer (score 1):

Try

```jsp
<sj:submit value="Submit All"  formIds="GeneralInfo,Corrugated1,Corrugated12,CustomerVendor"  />
```

According to the documentation on the site `formIds` attribute

> Comma delimited list of form ids for which to serialize all fields during submission when this element is clicked (if multiple forms have overlapping element names, it is indeterminate which will be used)

Comment: It should work for all forms, they shouldn't be nested (overlapped). How do you check that it's not working?

Comment: Is this what an exercise?

Comment: @ Roman Its working now. I had nested forms . Thanks for the reply and    I would like to know whether we can submit all forms by serializing in javascript.

Comment: yes, you can but it's already done by the code above, it uses jQuery internally. I didn't see their implementation, but I think it should be a multiple selector.